# cron job failing on date time format

Tags: date, time, cron

Have the following crontab entry:

```
*/10 * * * * cp /home/app/log/file.log.$(date --d="-1 day" +%Y%m%d) /root/
```

I can run the command successfully on the command line but it fails with the cronjob indicating the "+" is the issue

```
cp /home/app/log/file.log.$(date --d="-1 day" +

/bin/sh: -c line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ')'
```

Any thoughts on this?

Cheers,
Roland

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find the solution to my problem. I had to escape the %

```
*/10 * * * * cp /home/app/log/file.log.$(date --d="-1 day" +\%Y\%m\%d) /root/
```

according to this post: https://serverfault.com/questions/274475/escaping-double-quotes-and-percent-signs-in-cron